# Java. Cant add JPanel in JScrolledPane

Tags: java, swing, components, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane

I'm adding `JTabbedPane` to `JFrame`.

Each tab contains a different `bgPanel` (`JPanel` with drawn image as background), each `bgPanel` contains `JScrollPane`, and each `JScrollPane` contains a `JPane` (`nowyPanel`).

`bgPanels` are only a background. Each `JScrollPane` has `setOpaque(false);` and `getViewport().setOpaque(false);`. Each `JPanel` `nowyPanel` has `setOpaque(false);` only.

I can see the background and `JScrollPanels` but no `JPanels`. I Checked it and it seems that content is correctly added there. The problem is with `JPanels` which doesn't show up.

Here is some code:

```
static class JBackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;

    JBackgroundPanel() {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("2.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}

//method to add components to element of array nowyPanel[] JPanel
//i[a] and o are set earlier and they are fine
static void skrotyDoPaneli() {
    int a, b;
    for (a = 0; a < o; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b < i[a]; b++) {
            nowyPanel[a].add(new dodanieIkony(ikonki[a][b], podpisyIkonek[a][b], listaOdnosnikow[a][b]));
            nowyPanel[a].repaint();
            nowyPanel[a].revalidate();
        }
    }
}

//set properties for all panels 
static void ladowaniePaneli() {
    int b;
    Dimension osiemsetnaszescset = new Dimension(800, 600);
    for (b = 0; b < o; b++) {
        bgPanel[b] = new JBackgroundPanel();
        vertical[b] = new JScrollPane();
        nowyPanel[b] = new JPanel();

        ((FlowLayout) bgPanel[b].getLayout()).setVgap(0);
        bgPanel[b].setPreferredSize(osiemsetnaszescset);
        nowyPanel[b].setPreferredSize(osiemsetnaszescset);
        vertical[b].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(789, 517));
        vertical[b].setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        vertical[b].setOpaque(false);
        nowyPanel[b].setOpaque(false);
        vertical[b].getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        vertical[b].add(nowyPanel[b]);
        bgPanel[b].add(vertical[b]);
        vertical[b].add(nowyPanel[b]);
    }
}
//each element of bgPanel array is set as individual tab
static JTabbedPane tabbedPane() {
    JTabbedPane panelZakladek = new JTabbedPane();
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < o; j++) {
        panelZakladek.addTab(nazwyGrup[j], bgPanel[j]);
    }
    return panelZakladek;
}

//does everything what needs to be done before JFrame shows up
static void przedStartem() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    odczyt();
    odczytPaneli();
    ladowaniePaneli();
    skrotyDoPaneli();
}

//does przedStartem() and then initialize JFrame with content
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    przedStartem();
    //przywolanie do zycia okna glownego JFrame
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            glowneOkno okno = new glowneOkno();
            okno.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
//Variables Declaration
static int o = 0;
static int[] i = new int[1000];
static JBackgroundPanel[] bgPanel = new JBackgroundPanel[1000];
static JScrollPane[] vertical = new JScrollPane[1000];
static JPanel[] nowyPanel = new JPanel[1000];
static FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
static String[] nazwyGrup = new String[1000];
static File plikZGrupami = new File("grupy.txt");
static String[][] podpisyIkonek = new String[1000][1000];
static Icon[][] ikonki = new Icon[1000][1000];
static String[][] listaOdnosnikow = new String[1000][1000];
static File[][] listaPlikow = new File[1000][1000];
```

Comment: When all the variables and methods and classes are static you know you have a bad design. I suggest you look at the Swing tutorial for examples on how to better structure your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bgPanel[b].add(vertical[b]);
vertical[b].add(nowyPanel[b]);
```

Don't add components to a scrollpane. Instead the code should be:

```
vertical[b].setViewportView(nowyPanel[b]);
```

Comment: Thx for help. I just noticed it by myself too few sec ago. Dont know why i did it that way but now everything works fine. Your code works fine but becouse im more used to it I made it like that:
vertical[b] = new JScrollPane(nowyPanel[b]);

Comment: That is usually how I create a scrollPane as well.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that you've not changed the default layout manager of the `JPanel`, which is `FlowLayout`...Try changing the `JBackgroundPanel`'s layout manager to something like `BorderLayout` instead.

You should avoid using `setPreferredSize`.  The problem with this is it can be changed by some other part of the program.  Instead, you should override the `getPreferredSize` method, this should really be done within `JBackgroundPanel` class.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestBackgroundPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBackgroundPane();
    }

    public TestBackgroundPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            top.setOpaque(false);
            top.add(new JLabel("Look ma, no hands"));
            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
            sp.setOpaque(false);
            sp.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
            sp.setViewportView(top);
            add(sp);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.drawLine(getWidth(), 0, 0, getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```